# Zend Framework double Acl Resources with Modules

Tags: zend-framework, acl

I set up a new module admin, so I can perfectly access this module with www.example.com/admin - but I of course want to make this accessible only for administrators. Now, the controller obviously is "index" as well as the action. But as I want everyone to access www.example.com, which got the controller and action "index", too, I have the following lines in my Acl Plugin:

```
$acl->add(new Zend_Acl_Resource('index'));
$acl->add(new Zend_Acl_Resource('admin:index'));

$acl->allow(null, array('index'));

// admins can do anything
$acl->allow('administrator', null);
```

But this seems to work out for the admin module, too. How to restrict common users from the admin module? I tried already

```
$acl->deny('guest', 'admin:index', 'index');
```

but this doesn't seem to work. Help is very appreciated. Thank You and sorry for my poor English.

Best Regards.

Comment: did you define the roles anywhere? ie: guest and administrator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I often use separate session namespaces for both my admin and user frontends, as well as separate ACL's.

By having a separate session for my admin panel, a logged in user still has no ability to access the admin section regardless of ACL, because the Zend_Auth session for admin is completely isolated from the user session.

Here is a class I use for admin that extends Zend_Auth.  Notice how in getInstance it sets the storage to a different session namespace that the default Zend_Auth.

```
<?php

class My_Admin_Auth extends Zend_Auth
{
    protected function __construct()
    {}

    protected function __clone()
    {}

    public static function getInstance()
    {
        if (null === self::$_instance) {
            self::$_instance = new self();
            self::$_instance->setStorage(new Zend_Auth_Storage_Session('Zend_Auth_admin'));
        }

        return self::$_instance;
    }

    /**
     * Get an auth adapater instance suitable for authenticating agains
     * the administrator database.
     * @param string $username
     * @param string $password
     * @return Zend_Auth_Adapter_DbTable Adapter used to call $auth->authenticate($adapter);
     */
    public static function getAdapter($username, $password, $usersalt)
    {
        $db = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()
                                     ->getParam('bootstrap')
                                     ->getResource('db');

        $authAdapter = new Zend_Auth_Adapter_DbTable($db,
                                                     'administrators',
                                                     'username',
                                                     'password');

        $authAdapter->setIdentity($username)
                    ->setCredential($password)
                    ->setCredentialTreatment(
                        'SHA1(CONCAT(?,"' . $usersalt . '"))'
                    );

        return $authAdapter;
    }

    /**
     * Return a SHA-1 hashed and salted version of the entered password
     * @param string $plaintext  Password to hash, a static salt is also applied
     * @return string the hashed password
     */
    public static function hashAdminPassword($plaintext, $usersalt)
    {
        return sha1($plaintext . $usersalt);
    }
}
```

Alternative to that, you could define a separate ACL for your admin area which denies everything by default, then only add allow rules if the user is an admin when the class is instantiated.